# Undefined object when I want to calculate on typescript and firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a problem when I want to calculate the difference between two values that I have to count how much this user need to fulfilled the criteria. Here is the code

```
export class LihatlaporanPage {
  id : string;
  category : number;
  porsiMakan : any =[];
  hehe : any = [];
  saran : any;
  saranKarbo : string;
  saranProteinHewani : string;
  saranProteinNabati : string;
  saranLemak : string;
  Cukup : string;
  kurangKarbo : number;
  kurangLemak : number;
  kurangProteinHewani : number;
  kurangProteinNabati : number;

    console.log("karbohidrat",this.hehe.porsiKarbohidrat,this.porsiMakan.porsiKarbohidrat);
    console.log("ini data this.hehe",this.hehe);
   console.log("cek kurang makan",this.porsiMakan);
    //hitung kekurangan
    this.saran={};
    if(this.hehe.porsiKarbohidrat < this.porsiMakan.porsiKarbohidrat )
     {
       this.kurangKarbo = this.porsiMakan.porsiKarbohidrat -this.hehe.porsiKarbohidrat;  
       this.saran.saranKarbo = " porsi karbohidrat masih kurang" + this.kurangKarbo + " porsi !" ;
     }
     else if(this.hehe.porsiProteinHewani < this.porsiMakan.porsiProteinHewani )
     {
       this.kurangProteinHewani = this.porsiMakan.porsiProteinHewani -this.hehe.porsiProteinHewani;  
       this.saran.saranProteinHewani = " porsi Protein Hewani masih kurang" + this.kurangProteinHewani + " porsi !" ;
     }     
     else if(this.hehe.porsiProteinNabati < this.porsiMakan.porsiProteinNabati )
     {
       this.kurangProteinNabati = this.porsiMakan.porsiProteinNabati -this.hehe.porsiProteinNabati;  
       this.saran.saranProteinNabati = " porsi Protein Nabati masih kurang" + this.kurangProteinNabati + " porsi !" ;
     }
     else if(this.hehe.porsiLemak < this.porsiMakan.porsiLemak )
     {
       this.kurangLemak = this.porsiMakan.porsiLemak-this.hehe.porsiLemak;  
       this.saran.saranLemak = " porsi Lemak masih kurang" + this.kurangLemak + " porsi !" ;
     }
     else 
     {
       this.saran.Cukup= "Sudah cukup";
     }

     console.log("saran porsi",this.saran);
  }
```

this is the code,

```
console.log("ini data this.hehe",this.hehe);
   console.log("cek kurang makan",this.porsiMakan);
```

This code give a true value so how I got the data is true, but when I want to 
  compare that two things to find the result its always go to else option.

also when I want to find the value like this

```
console.log("karbohidrat",this.hehe.porsiKarbohidrat,this.porsiMakan.porsiKarbohidrat);
```

it shows undefined.

here is what it looks like on the console :
[image: console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this.hehe**   &   **this.porsoMakan**   are arrays.
You shoud use:

```
console.log("karbohidrat",this.hehe[0].porsiKarbohidrat,this.porsiMakan[0].porsiKarbohidrat);
```

So for the if condition use this:

```
if(this.hehe[0].porsiKarbohidrat < this.porsiMakan[0].porsiKarbohidrat )
```

Comment: if there is many things for example 5 data, what should i do ?

Comment: I don't know it depends on what you want to do. But in most cases you'll need to do a loop for

Comment: how to do for with it ? should i add for and the condition on for ? and then counter it?

Comment: for (let i=0; i <this.hehe.length &&  i< this.porsiKarbohidrat; i++){  if(this.hehe[i].porsiKarbohidrat < this.porsiMakan[i].porsiKarbohidrat )